# using mockito with IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, mocking, mockito

I am new to Java, and my background mainly in .NET.
I am trying to use mockito in a java project in IntelliJ.
I am trying to follow this simple example:

http://code.google.com/p/mockito/

so, I added the library mockito-all-1.9.5.jar to the folder
c:\{my app path}\web\app\WEB-INF\lib

and I added in IntelliJ using Project Structure and then Libraries.

and I created a test class and add the following

import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
and I am getting this error:

"static imports are not supported at this language level"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Under *File - Project structure - Project*, make sure to have the project language level set to at least 5.0. (I would expect 6.0 or 7.0 now). Static imports are indeed supported only since Java 5.

Also, Mockito is used only in tests, and has thus no reason to be part of the deployed libraries of the webapp. It should thus not be under WEB-INF/lib.

Comment: Thanks JB
That was the problem. I was supporting an old app with Java 4.
So, what alternative I can use as mocking framework with Java 4?

Comment: You're not forced to use static imports. Just use `Mockito.when()` instead of `when()` (and same for all the other static methods). That said, I don't know if Mockito supports Java 1.4. I doubt it does. And I have no idea of a mocking framework that does. Look for old versions of Mockito or EasyMock to see if one exists which supports Java 1.4.

Answer (score 0):

If your question was about using Mockito with Java on Android, then note that you also need to include the following two Libraries:

dexmaker-1.0.jar
dexmaker-mockito-1.0.jar

to allow Mockito to work with the Dalvik JVM in Android.